# What is the most flexible and proper way to change different rows of a record on different pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just have Book record and I want to have a few pages to change info about the Book:

http://example.com/books/1/edit/photos - here I would like to have a form to upload photos

http://example.com/books/1/edit/reviews - here I want to add some reviews

http://example.com/books/1/edit/authors - here, change or add new authors

Is it possible not to create separate action for each edit page and do it in one 'edit' action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup some has_many models to handle the relational data associated with your books, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association.

One this is done you can create some forms to handle these relationships quite easily.

If you are new to rails you may want to look at using an admin interface system such as [activeadmin](http://www.activeadmin.info/) which will help you set this sort of thing up.

Comment: Thank you but my question is not about model associations and nested form but about a way to not to create an separate action for each edit page of the thing (Book). I am going to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different forms in each of the views that only expose the parts you want to edit there and have each of those forms post to the same `update` action.

If you use `form_for @book`, the form will always post to `/books/:id`.

And you can add a `before_filter` to your controller, that retrieves the book record, then you don't need to create individual actions for those views:

```
class BooksController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :load_book

private
  def load_book
    @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This makes the `@book` available to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a different member_action for each action like editing photos and reviews. In each member_action you can create the forms for editing with f.input. The tricky part will be the redirects. You will probably want to redirect from photos to authors with a redirect_to call